# Scalar product of a vector $x$ with a class of vectors equals zero implies that $x=0$?

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, orthogonality

Assume that $v_1, \dots, v_n \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ are distinct real numbers. Define
$$
v^k = (v_1^k, \dots, v_n^k) \in \mathbb{R}^n.
$$

Assume that $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are two arbitrary vectors such that
$$
\langle x,v^{2j+1} \rangle = 0 = \langle y,v^{2j} \rangle \ \ \ \ \forall j = 0,1,2,\dots
$$

That means the scalar product of $x$ with $v^k$ is equal to zero for all odd values of $k$ and the scalar product of $y$ with $v^k$ is equal to zero for all even values of $k$. Can we conclude that $x$ and $y$ are equal to zero?

Comment: By $\forall j=0,1,2,...$ do you mean $\forall j=0,1,2,...,n$ or do you wish the statement to be true for arbitrarily large $j$ ?

Comment: Assume all $|v_i|$ are distinct, the statement is true because the $n \times n$ [Vandermonde matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix)  $(v_i^{2(j-1)})_{1 \le i,j \le n}$ is invertible.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take $v_1= 1, v_2=-1$ and $v_i$  what you want for $i \geq 3$. In this way you get

> $v^{2j} = (1,1,\dots)$ and $v^{2j+1}= (1,-1,\dots)$ for every $j = 0,1,\dots$

Now, consider  $y = (1,-1,0, \dots, 0) \in \mathbb{R^n}$, then $\langle y,v^{2j} \rangle = 0$ for every $j$.

Analogously you can take $x = (1,1,0,\dots,0)$ and observe that $\langle x,v^{2j+1} \rangle = 0$ for every $j$.

These should be counterexamples of your statement.

**P.S.**: doing this I supposed $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle $ is the standard scalar product  , i.e. $\langle x,y\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i y_i$.

As Achille suggested you have to require a stronger condition in order to get a true statement.